# Using Excel VBA to find exact multi-column match and then combining/merging rows

Tags: excel, vba

I was told to re-post this with more data and code, so here we go. Hoping this is satisfactory this time.

I'm trying to take an excel database and combine/merge matching columns into one row using VBA. The initial data would look something like this (There are quite a bit more data points in reality, and I would be matching on more columns and combining more rows):

Initial Data

[image]

And turn it into one that looks like this:

Merged Data

[image]

What I need to do is match exactly on columns A:E (State, Last, First, Age, Class) and if they do, combine/merge columns F:I (20', 19', 18', 17') into a single row. Also, I'd like it to delete the information from the columns that it combines/merges (F:I) on one of the rows. For example, with the Robert Johnson merge/combine; If you look at the above table, one row has all the information from F:I in it, but both rows still have all the information from A:E.

The closest I have been able to get it to work is by using the code (I found elsewhere and didn't create):

```
[COLOR=#008000]'Dim 2 search cells[/COLOR]
Dim BlankCell As Range
Dim IdCell As Range

[COLOR=#008000]
'Find Last row and column[/COLOR]

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Dim lColumn As Long
lColumn = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

[COLOR=#008000]'Set the area to consider[/COLOR]

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, lColumn))

[COLOR=#008000] 'Select​ each blank cell in area[/COLOR]

Rng.Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select

 [COLOR=#008000]'And replace it with appropriate value[/COLOR]
    For Each BlankCell In Selection
             For Each IdCell In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, 1))
                      If (IdCell.Value = Cells(BlankCell.Row, 1).Value And Cells(IdCell.Row, BlankCell.Column) <> "") Then
                        BlankCell = Cells(IdCell.Row, BlankCell.Column).Value
                      End If
             Next IdCell
    Next BlankCell

[COLOR=#008000] 'Then​ erase duplicate lines[/COLOR]
    Rng.Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, lColumn)).RemoveDuplicates     Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), _
    Header:=xlYes
```

It doesn't match right though because the output looks like this:

Not Quite Right

[image]

It looks to be matching on the first column only and not the first 5. It is also not combining/deleting the data right.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Why not use a query where you remove duplicates and pull the remaining values instead of using VBA?

Comment: I suggest using a `Dictionary` to hold your data. The dictionary key would be a combination of the State, Last, First, Age, Class fields. Ideally, you could create a Class to hold a common record of data in the Dictionary too. When the merge is complete, just output the results back to a worksheet.

Comment: @MarkS. What do you mean by pulling the remaining values? I know how to remove the duplicates, but i don't know how to get the data into a single row before removing them.

Comment: If you use power query to pull the data, remove duplicates and create a table with what left, you can use those same columns to sumifs any metrics you would like to have summarized, or if there's a way to achieve something similar in power query use that.

Comment: So you want to keep all the original rows of data, but only move data (20', 19', 18', 17') from the duplicate rows up to a single row?  Then you're keeping the duplicate rows, but with empty data?

Comment: @PeterT - That is correct. Much better way of phrasing it than I provided.